# FB platform sample app WishList on iOS and Heroku failed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku, facebook-ios-sdk

I tried WishList app on [public fbsamples on github](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-android-wishlist). After following all the steps and setting backend server. There's no problem uploading a photo on heroku. (I check heroku logs)
But runtime error shows that there's problem posting on timeline(domain = com.facebook.sdk, code = 5)

The console messages:

> Response from photo upload:
>   {"image_name":"505b5df82ca2e.jpg","image_url":"http://XXX.herokuapp.com/images/505b5df82ca2e.jpg"}
>     Error: HTTP status code: 400
>     error: domain = com.facebook.sdk, code = 5

Print the error out in the following:

> ```
>    "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" 
>    UserInfo=0xe07c760 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={type = mutable dict, count   >= 2,entries =>
>    1 : {contents = "code"} = {value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
>    2 : {contents = "body"} = {type = mutable dict, count = 1,entries =>
>    11 : {contents = "error"} = {type = mutable dict, count = 3,entries =>
>    2 : {contents = "type"} = {contents = "OAuthException"}
>    3 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "(#100) Only one of wishlist, product >reference objects can be specified for type MY_APP_SPACE:add_to."}
>    6 : {contents = "code"} = 100
>    }
>    }
>    }
>    , com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
> ```

Any suggestion?

BTW, I use Facebook SDK 3.0.8. I tried the newest 3-1.0.8 too. But meet the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check how you've set up your "add_to" action type. Go to your App Dashboard and then edit the add_to action type. You should be seeing "Wishlist" as a connected object and "Product" listed as one of the properties. The error is probably due to the setup you have that assumes you're either "adding to" a wishlist or "adding to" a product. However you're actually adding to a wishlist and passing in a product reference.

This is the fbsamples README snippet that you want to double-check you followed:

Edit your "add to" action type once more to add a reference to the "product" object:

Under action properties click on "add another property". enter "product" in the name field. select "product" for the type field.